# How to display a Layout element from ViewModel (MVVM) in XAML using Compiled Binding

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm

i'm new to XAML and MVVM. I'm trying to redo the [Minesweeper sample from Xamarin docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/vi-vn/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/bugsweeper/) using MVVM pattern.

Problem is my Board model is an AbsoluteLayout

```
public class Board : AbsoluteLayout
{
    const int COL = 9;
    const int ROW = 9;
    public int MINES = 10;

    public Tile[,] board = new Tile[ROW, COL];
}
```

I want to display the Board to the view like in the sample. However using the Compiled Binding only get me to the ViewModel - named ClassicGame

```
<ContentPage
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:local = "clr-namespace:MineSweeper.ViewModel"
x:Class="MineSweeper.View.ClassicGamePage">

<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout x:DataType="local:ClassicGame">
        <Label Text="{Binding GameMode}"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Instructions}"/>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="{Binding MinesLeft, StringFormat='Number of mines left {0}'}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding FlagNumber, StringFormat='Number of flags {0}'}"/>
            <local:ClassicGame ???>

        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

The tag <local:ClassicGame > can only reach to ClassicGame object - which cannot be displayed as it is not a UI element.
Is there any possible way that can display the board as View element?

Comment: "my Board model is an AbsoluteLayout" - any Layout will be part of the view, not a model.  You need to separate the model of your game from it's visual representation.

Comment: thinking of that way, i have the idea to create the visual representation of the Board using Grid layout. Is it good? Because i have seen in the documents that "The Grid layout should not be confused with tables, and is not intended to present tabular data. Unlike HTML tables, a Grid is intended for laying out content." It is confusing of phrase tabular data.

Comment: @LongTran Yes,  [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/choose-layout) is used for displaying elements in rows and columns, you can try to use it.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT yes!! Thank you for your advice really much! i'm trying to use Grid now